# Folder projects SmartBear soapui maven plugin

Tags: soapui

I use the version 5.1.3 of the plugin SmartBear SoapUI "com.smartbear.soapui" under maven. Is it possible to define only the name of the xml files folder instead of the full path at the tag  to run a list of projects of the same folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with redfish4ktc you can do this

Example :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>soapUI1</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-multi</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectFiles>
                            <scan>
                                <baseDirectory>./soapui/projects</baseDirectory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*_suffix.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </scan>
                        </projectFiles>
                        <outputFolder>./outputfolder</outputFolder>
                        <junitReport>false</junitReport>
                        <useOutputFolderPerProject>true</useOutputFolderPerProject>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

add to run this just execute the maven command :

```
mvn test com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui:maven-soapui-extension-plugin:4.6.4.2:test-multi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [refish plugin](https://github.com/redfish4ktc/maven-soapui-extension-plugin) to execute all projects located in a folder. Or existing soapui-maven-plugin with multiple execution sections (each execution with one soapui project xml file)

Comment: The plugin redfish4ktc is not stable. And the second solution with multiple execution sections involves changing pom.xml every time where I have a new script SoapUI